# Set optional property null with checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

i'm creating WPF application with MVVM pattern, i have 9 textboxes, which are binded to the appropriate properties in my viewmodel, also i have 9 checkboxes,  and each textboxe's attribute "IsEnabled" is binded to checkboxe's "IsChacked". The thing is, i don't want just to disable textboxes with checkboxes, i also want to set the binded to textbox property to null, when it's disabled. I didn't find an elegant way to do that yet. Here is the code for 1 textbox and 1 checkbox to clirify what i mean:

```
<CheckBox Name="ArtikelGruppeChkBox"  
          Content="Artikel gruppe" />
<TextBox Margin="0,29,365,173" 
         Text="{Binding ArtikelGruppe}" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ArtikelGruppeChkBox,Path=IsChecked,TargetNullValue=false }" />
```

And i want to set property ArtikelGruppe to null, when chekbox sets unchecked and disables textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a business logic rule because you want to assign a particular value (NULL) when something else changes; I'd go for an update in your viewmodel.
You could create bool props in your viewmodel and bind to every checkbox so that when the prop change from true to false you could simple change the corresponding value bound to your textbox.
Even for testing purposes, the viewmodel approach is better